# Bootstrap onClick change tab and target a new windows at the same time

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

So I have a button in one of my bootstrap tab-content and I have about 5 nav-tabs.  What I want to do is when you click on the button to go to the final tab and launch a new window at the same time.

Here is what I've tried.

```
 <a href="#done" 
 onClick="window.open('https://amazon.com', '_blank')" 
 class="btn btn-success"> Marketplace</a>
```

It launches the new window but the tab doesn't move to the final tab.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a click handler that handles the bootstrap tab change and opens a window. You can put the URL you want for each tab in a data attribute of the element and read that in dynamically.

Since the SO sandbox won't allow a popup, here's a codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dRYOmE

```js
$('#myTabs a').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show');
  window.open($(this).attr('data-url'), '_blank');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTabs">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" data-url="http://www.amazon.com" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" data-url="http://www.stackoverflow.com" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" data-url="http://www.google.com" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">home</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">profile</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">messages</div>
  </div>

</div>
```